# viewDidAppear loads after CellForRowAtIndex when trying for the second time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

On my first load all works great. Here is my NSlog

```
2013-03-07 09:15:57.289 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting viewDidLoad
2013-03-07 09:15:57.775 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting viewDidAppear
2013-03-07 09:15:58.518 SAMPLE[10566:207] all done!
2013-03-07 09:15:58.518 SAMPLE[10566:207] stories array has 4 items
2013-03-07 09:15:58.527 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting CellForRowAtIndex
```

But when i click the back button in the navigation and click on the view again it hangs until the cells are populated. See NSlog Below

```
2013-03-07 09:16:06.252 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting viewDidLoad
2013-03-07 09:16:06.309 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting CellForRowAtIndex
2013-03-07 09:16:07.019 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting CellForRowAtIndex
2013-03-07 09:16:07.679 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting CellForRowAtIndex
2013-03-07 09:16:08.198 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting CellForRowAtIndex
2013-03-07 09:16:09.242 SAMPLE[10566:207] -->Starting viewDidAppear
```

My viewDidAppear has the following in this.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"-->Starting viewDidAppear");   

     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([[xmlParser branch] count] == 0) {
         [self loadDatafromServer];   // Goes and runs my XML Parser and fill the array.

    }
         [self loadBranchs];  // This just loads my annotations for my map
  [self.tableView reloadData];       
}
```

Any idea here. As i said, first time she loads perfect, but if a user goes back and comes in it populates the cells first causing a delay. I want it to open the view and then populate. The indicator will show them then its loading.

Comment: i guess you need to implement viewWillAppear in place of viewDidAppear.

Comment: Are you calling [self.tableView reloadData] in viewDidLoad also?

Comment: @GopeshGupta Yes I am, same problem.

Comment: remove that one from viewDidLoad.

Comment: @GopeshGupta Same problem.

Comment: @Neelz no, if i change it then even the first load hangs till its populated.

Comment: Are you calling [self.tableView reloadData] in viewWillAppear also?

Comment: @GopeshGupta no im not calling it in viewWillAppear, but i did try and same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't implement that task in viewDidAppear,as this method performs additional tasks associated with it before presenting the view.So the delay.So better implement it in viewWillAppear method.

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     [super viewWillDidAppear:animated];

        if ([[xmlParser branch] count] == 0) {
             [self loadDatafromServer];   // Goes and runs my XML Parser and fill the array.

        }
             [self loadBranchs];  // This just loads my annotations for my map
      [self.tableView reloadData];       
    }
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: THanks for the feedback. No if i do this. when i click to go to the view, it hangs until the cells are populated. First time and second time.

Comment: @SnakeBlisken...what are the operations you're performing on viewdidload and viewwillappear method?

Comment: In ViewDidLoad im just loading the mapview coordinates, and nothing in ViewWillAppear.